# Notepad++ Jump between opening and closing html tags

Tags: html, notepad++

If I've currently got a html tag highlighted in Notepad++, is there a way to automatically jump to the closing tag and vice-versa?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on SO

Comment: You might be right there Dana, cheers!

Comment: You can do this in sublime text if you install emmet plugin. Works like a charm - choose to highlight till closing tag.

Comment: If you nested the HTML tags correctly with start and end tag, you can see a + or - sign on left side of Notepad++.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes there is, you can use the "html tag" plugin and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

From the plugin's description:

> This plug-in provides two core functions to Notepad++: HTML and XML tag matching, like the built-in brace matching (Ctrl+B / Shift+Ctrl+B) HTML entity encoding/decoding (example: e to é and vice versa)
>   Author: Martijn Coppoolse
>   Source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/HTMLTag/HTMLTag%20plugin%20v0.3/HTMLTag_plugin_v0.3.0_unicode.zip/download

Comment: This plugin is extremely slow and crashes when used on ending tags in a very large XML file (20k lines).

Answer (score 1):

This workaround has worked for me:

1. Close section
2. Click on left margin one line under the closed section to add a marker
3. Open the section again
4. Hit F2 to jump to the marker
5. Click on the marker to remove it

I came here looking for an easier way, but this might be the easiest thing without installing plugins.

Comment: I prefer this to a buggy plugin. Good tip. Thanks.

Comment: Can this be turned into a macro?

Answer (score 0):

For the big file I was working on, my workaround to find the extra/missing div was to rename a copy of the file to file.java. Then replace "/div" with } and "div" with {.